# How do I filter files in a directory by month, zip them based on month, rename them, place them in a folder that contains the zipfiles?

Tags: java, directory, zip, filtering, file-rename

I have a directory with over 1000 files and I need to zip them based on the month, rename them and place the zipped files in a folder. I usually do this manually but I'm tired of doing it this way. I have written a program that renames files and places them in a new folder but I don't know how to filter by month or zip them using java on Windows 10.

```
        String path = "C:\\\\Users\\\\srs\\\\Desktop\\\\Test\\notProcessed";

        File[] filelist = new File(path).listFiles();

        for (File file : filelist) {
            Date d = new Date(file.lastModified());
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(d);
            int iyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int imonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            String syear = Integer.toString(iyear);
            String smonth = Integer.toString(imonth);
            System.out.println(syear + "_" + smonth);
            String destpath = "C:\\\\Users\\\\srs\\\\Desktop\\\\Test\\notProcessed\\\\TestZip\\\\";
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destpath + syear + "_" + smonth + ".zip");
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
                System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + file);
                System.out.println("File Added : " + file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                zos.closeEntry();
                zos.close();
                System.out.println("Done");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

So this is what I have so far. The program runs but it doesn't give me the the required result. It should be giving me 3 zip folders labeled(that are based on `lastModified()`) 2019_07, 2019_08, 2019_09 but I'm getting 2019_06, 2019_07, 2019_08, 2019_10 with only 1 file in each.

Comment: Please add information about your OS. Also, show us the code of your program, maybe someone can add this functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "_filter by month_"? Should only files before a certain month be included? Or do you group files by month and each group goes in their own ZIP file? How does the `cutoff` factor into this?

Comment: Only files from previous month, not current month, get grouped by month and each group goes into their own zip. `cutoff` was used in a previous to get files older than 2 days. I'm not sure if I would be using it in the program trying to be written.

Answer (score 0):

## Grouping

You're currently using the `File` API and the old date-time API (e.g. `Date`). I'm going to suggest you:

1. Use the `java.nio.file` API instead of the `File` API.
2. Use the `java.time` API, added in Java 8, instead of the old date-time API.

   - This one is of particular importance. When creating new code one should avoid the old date-time API at all costs.

From what I understand of your question you want to group files by the year and month of their last modified time and put them in their own ZIP file. For the grouping we can use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class and the [`Files#walkFileTree(Path,Set,int,FileVisitor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,java.util.Set,int,java.nio.file.FileVisitor)) method. Here's an example:

```java
Map<YearMonth, List<Path>> groupFiles(Path dir, int depth) throws IOException {
  Map<YearMonth, List<Path>> result = new HashMap<>();

  Files.walkFileTree(dir, Set.of(), depth, new SimpleFileVisitor<>() {

    private final ZoneId systemZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    private final YearMonth currentYearMonth = YearMonth.now();

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
      YearMonth yearMonth = getYearMonthOfLastModifiedTime(attrs);
      if (yearMonth.isBefore(currentYearMonth)) {
        result.computeIfAbsent(yearMonth, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(file);
      }
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    private YearMonth getYearMonthOfLastModifiedTime(BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
      Instant lastModInstant = attrs.lastModifiedTime().toInstant();
      return YearMonth.from(LocalDate.ofInstant(lastModInstant, systemZone));
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

The above is using the system default time-zone. I also add the option to specify the maximum depth to go to when searching the file tree (rooted at `dir`). If you only want to find files that are direct children of `dir` then use `1`. Also, in the case where the max depth will *always* be `1`, you could use a `DirectoryStream` instead of a `FileVisitor`.

Note that to get a `Path` instance you can call `File#toPath()`. Since we're trying to avoid the `File` class, however, it'd be better to use [`Path#of(String,String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) (or, if not using Java 11+, `Paths#get`). For example:

```java
Path path = Path.of("C:", "Users", "srs", "Desktop", "Test", "notProcessed");
```

The above `Path` will be associated with the default `FileSystem`.

---

## Creating ZIP

Once you have the files grouped by the `YearMonth` of their last modified time you need to put them in a ZIP file. Within the JDK there are at least two options for creating ZIP files:

1. The `java.util.zip` API.
2. The [*ZIP File System Provider*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html) (used via the `java.nio.file` API).

The first option, I believe, gives you more control over the compression process. However, the second option lets you treat a ZIP file the same as any other file system in a transparent manner. For this answer I'll show an example of the second option:

```java
List<Path> compressFiles(Path zipDir, Map<YearMonth, List<Path>> groupedFiles) 
    throws IOException {
  List<Path> zipFiles = new ArrayList<>(groupedFiles.size());

  DateTimeFormatter zipFilenameFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu_MM'.zip'");
  for (Map.Entry<YearMonth, List<Path>> entry : groupedFiles.entrySet()) {
    Path zipFile = zipDir.resolve(zipFilenameFormatter.format(entry.getKey()));
    zipFiles.add(zipFile);

    URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipFile.toUri());
    Map<String, ?> env = Map.of("create", Boolean.toString(Files.notExists(zipFile)));
    try (FileSystem zipFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
      Path zipRoot = zipFileSystem.getRootDirectories().iterator().next();
      for (Path source : entry.getValue()) {
        Files.move(source, zipRoot.resolve(source.getFileName().toString()));
      }
    }
  }

  return zipFiles;
}
```

I use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) because your question indicates the filenames of the ZIP files should be `year_month.zip` (with an underscore). The `YearMonth#toString()` method will return `year-month` (with a dash) so the `DateTimeFormatter` is used to separate the year and month by an underscore. If you don't mind the dash then you can create the filename simply using `yearMonth.toString() + ".zip"`.

The above uses [`Files#move(Path,Path,CopyOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) to actually add the file to the ZIP file. The file will be compressed. Note this will fail if an entry with that name already exists in the ZIP file, but you can change this by using `REPLACE_EXISTING`. The call to `#move` will delete the source file; if that's not desired then consider using `Files#copy` instead.

Note I use `Path#resolve(String)` instead of `Path#resolve(Path)` because the latter requires, in my experience, that the two `Path` instances belong to the same provider.